# How to create Sharing Service in Mac Catalyst?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I have created a Mac Catalyst version of my iOS App. I am facing problem to achieve Share Functionality in MacCatalyst.

**How to create sharing functionality like this in Mac Catalyst?**

[image]

I want to share Text with it.

Comment: Hint: UIActivityViewController

Comment: Check this out: https://www.mattmoriarity.com/2019-10-18-share-menus-with-mac-catalyst/

Comment: Hint 2: Retain your UIActivityViewController! Otherwise it won't work. And if saving images, set scale to 1 -> `UIImage(cgImage: cg, scale: 1, orientation: input.imageOrientation)`